# High chart export not working in android webview

Tags: php, highcharts, export

Can anyone please help me to figure out why high chart export (download png) feature not working in mobile browser?while I tried its demo http://www.highcharts.com/demo in mobile browser and it is working fine.Please help me.

**Edit** here are the codes from export.js which is responsible for file download -

```
  f.post(a.url, {
            filename: a.filename || "chart",
            type: a.type,
            width: a.width || 0,
            scale: a.scale || 2,
            svg: e
        },
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might have to give some more information (code) on how your implementation differs from the demo.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by trick, may be it will be useful for you also,so I download export.js and modify it as -

```
exportChart: function(t, e) {
        var n = this.getSVGForExport(t, e),
            t = u(this.options.exporting, t),
            o = {
                filename: t.filename,
                type: t.type,
                width: t.width || 0,
                scale: t.scale || 2,
                svg: n,
                async: !0
            };
        $.post(t.url, o, function(e) {
            var n = t.url + e,
                o = document.URL,
                i = "chartUrl",
                r = n,
                a = new RegExp("([?&])" + i + "=.*?(&|$)", "i"),
                s = -1 !== o.indexOf("?") ? "&" : "?";
            o.match(a) ? currentUrl = o.replace(a, "$1" + i + "=" + r + "$2") : currentUrl = o + s + i + "=" + r, window.open(currentUrl, "_self")
        })
    },
```

And at android side, I have following codes -

```
f (url != null) { //url = current web url
String arr[] = url.split("=");
if (arr != null && arr.length == 2) {
    String newUrl = arr[1];
    if (newUrl != null && !newUrl.equals("")) {
        String fileName = newUrl.substring(newUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, newUrl.length());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Start Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "newUrl : " + newUrl);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(newUrl));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
    }
}}
```